# Onscroll, make a action

Tags: javascript, facebook

Is it possible to detect when a user is scrolling on a facebook canvas application (In a iframe).
So i can make an action when the user scrolls down on the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can go for the jQuery API and try out their [scroll()](http://api.jquery.com/scroll/) event to detect the mouse scroll...

**UPDATE**

```
$(window).load(function(){
    $($('iframe').contents()).scroll(function(){
       alert('frame scrolled in jquery');
    }); 
});
```

Comment: I've also tried that, but it's just like my application doesn't know i'm scrolling (maybe because of, that the application is inside an iframe?)

Comment: Doesn't work either. It's a bit weired, that it doesn't work :s

Comment: Yearh allright, will you do that and report back when you have a super solution, would be a huge help! :-)

Comment: anything new @Coding freak? :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can detect it through the event listener "DOMMouseScroll". [This page](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/2009/08/javascript-mouse-scroll-event-down-example.html) provides a good example of working with it.

Comment: It doesn't work. When i try to scroll with that javascript code inside my facebook application, nothing happens :-(

Comment: You would have to modify it to where you reach "outside" of the iframe. @Coding Freaks solution ought to work, provided you're using jQuery.

Comment: I'm using jQuery and tried his code inside my iframe, but nothing happend. Did you try it or do you have a live example on a facebook application or something? :-)

Comment: Except that won't work for detecting scroll caused by: keyboard scrolling, focusing an input outside of current scroll visible area, scrollbar scrolling, touch scrolling.

Comment: @robocat Yes, I noticed that later on. Hence, why my answer isn't the chosen one :)